# How to generate a schema from a CSV for a PostgreSQL Copy

Tags: postgresql, csv, schema, postgresql-copy

Given a CSV with several dozen or more columns, how can a 'schema' be created that can be used in a CREATE TABLE SQL expression in PostgreSQL for use with the COPY tool?

I see plenty of examples for the COPY tool, and basic CREATE TABLE expressions, but nothing goes into detail about cases when you have a potentially prohibitive number of columns for manual creation of the schema.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

If the CSV is not excessively large and available on your local machine then [csvkit](https://github.com/wireservice/csvkit) is the simplest solution. It also contains a number of other utilities for working with CSVs, so it is a [usefull tool](https://source.opennews.org/en-US/articles/eleven-awesome-things-you-can-do-csvkit/) to know in general.

At its simplest typing into the shell:

```
$ csvsql myfile.csv
```

will print out the required `CREATE TABLE` SQL command, which can be saved to a file using output redirection.

If you also provide a connection string `csvsql` will create the table and upload the file in one go:

```
$ csvsql --db "$MY_DB_URI" --insert myfile.csv
```

There are also options to specify the flavor of SQL and CSV you are working with. They are documented in the builtin help:

```
$ csvsql -h
usage: csvsql [-h] [-d DELIMITER] [-t] [-q QUOTECHAR] [-u {0,1,2,3}] [-b]
              [-p ESCAPECHAR] [-z MAXFIELDSIZE] [-e ENCODING] [-S] [-H] [-v]
              [--zero] [-y SNIFFLIMIT]
              [-i {access,sybase,sqlite,informix,firebird,mysql,oracle,maxdb,postgresql,mssql}]
              [--db CONNECTION_STRING] [--query QUERY] [--insert]
              [--tables TABLE_NAMES] [--no-constraints] [--no-create]
              [--blanks] [--no-inference] [--db-schema DB_SCHEMA]
              [FILE [FILE ...]]

Generate SQL statements for one or more CSV files, create execute those
statements directly on a database, and execute one or more SQL queries.
positional arguments:
  FILE                  The CSV file(s) to operate on. If omitted, will accept
                        input on STDIN.

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -d DELIMITER, --delimiter DELIMITER
                        Delimiting character of the input CSV file.
  -t, --tabs            Specifies that the input CSV file is delimited with
                        tabs. Overrides "-d".
  -q QUOTECHAR, --quotechar QUOTECHAR
                        Character used to quote strings in the input CSV file.
  -u {0,1,2,3}, --quoting {0,1,2,3}
                        Quoting style used in the input CSV file. 0 = Quote
                        Minimal, 1 = Quote All, 2 = Quote Non-numeric, 3 =
                        Quote None.
  -b, --doublequote     Whether or not double quotes are doubled in the input
                        CSV file.
  -p ESCAPECHAR, --escapechar ESCAPECHAR
                        Character used to escape the delimiter if --quoting 3
                        ("Quote None") is specified and to escape the
                        QUOTECHAR if --doublequote is not specified.
  -z MAXFIELDSIZE, --maxfieldsize MAXFIELDSIZE
                        Maximum length of a single field in the input CSV
                        file.
  -e ENCODING, --encoding ENCODING
                        Specify the encoding the input CSV file.
  -S, --skipinitialspace
                        Ignore whitespace immediately following the delimiter.
  -H, --no-header-row   Specifies that the input CSV file has no header row.
                        Will create default headers.
  -v, --verbose         Print detailed tracebacks when errors occur.
  --zero                When interpreting or displaying column numbers, use
                        zero-based numbering instead of the default 1-based
                        numbering.
  -y SNIFFLIMIT, --snifflimit SNIFFLIMIT
                        Limit CSV dialect sniffing to the specified number of
                        bytes. Specify "0" to disable sniffing entirely.
  -i {access,sybase,sqlite,informix,firebird,mysql,oracle,maxdb,postgresql,mssql}, --dialect {access,sybase,sqlite,informix,firebird,mysql,oracle,maxdb,postgresql,mssql}
                        Dialect of SQL to generate. Only valid when --db is
                        not specified.
  --db CONNECTION_STRING
                        If present, a sqlalchemy connection string to use to
                        directly execute generated SQL on a database.
  --query QUERY         Execute one or more SQL queries delimited by ";" and
                        output the result of the last query as CSV.
  --insert              In addition to creating the table, also insert the
                        data into the table. Only valid when --db is
                        specified.
  --tables TABLE_NAMES  Specify one or more names for the tables to be
                        created. If omitted, the filename (minus extension) or
                        "stdin" will be used.
  --no-constraints      Generate a schema without length limits or null
                        checks. Useful when sampling big tables.
  --no-create           Skip creating a table. Only valid when --insert is
                        specified.
  --blanks              Do not coerce empty strings to NULL values.
  --no-inference        Disable type inference when parsing the input.
  --db-schema DB_SCHEMA
                        Optional name of database schema to create table(s)
                        in.
```

Several other tools also do schema inference including:

- Apache Spark
- Pandas (Python)
- Blaze (Python)
- read.csv + your favorite db package in R

Each of these have functionality to read a CSV (and other formats) into a tabular data structure usually called a DataFrame or similar, inferring the column types in the process. They then have other commands to either write out an equivalent SQL schema or upload the DataFrame directly into a specified database. The choice of tool will depend on the volume of data, how it is stored, idiosyncrasies of your CSV, the target database and the language you prefer to work in.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the workflow to create that SQL schema and/or upload the csv with the inferred schema to a database? That's the real meat and potatoes of what I'm trying to figure out... Many thanks!!!

Comment: @DPSSpatial I have added a description for doing this with csvkit, which should be applicable in most situations.

Comment: YES. This is fantastic - thank you again for adding this answer!! Lots of great stuff in CSVKIT!

Answer (score 14):

Basically you should prepare the data (including its structure) outside the database, with ready-made tools or using python, ruby or a language of your choice. 
However, in the lack of such opportunities you can do much using plpgsql.

### Creating a table with text columns

Files in csv format do not contain any information about column types, primary or foreign keys etc.
You can relatively easily create a table with text columns and copy data to it. 
After that you should manually alter types of columns and add constraints.

```
create or replace function import_csv(csv_file text, table_name text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    create temp table import (line text) on commit drop;
    execute format('copy import from %L', csv_file);

    execute format('create table %I (%s);', 
        table_name, concat(replace(line, ',', ' text, '), ' text'))
    from import limit 1;

    execute format('copy %I from %L (format csv, header)', table_name, csv_file);
end $$;
```

Example data in the file `c:\data\test.csv`:

```
id,a_text,a_date,a_timestamp,an_array
1,str 1,2016-08-01,2016-08-01 10:10:10,"{1,2}"
2,str 2,2016-08-02,2016-08-02 10:10:10,"{1,2,3}"
3,str 3,2016-08-03,2016-08-03 10:10:10,"{1,2,3,4}"
```

Import:

```
select import_csv('c:\data\test.csv', 'new_table');

select * from new_table;

 id | a_text |   a_date   |     a_timestamp     | an_array  
----+--------+------------+---------------------+-----------
 1  | str 1  | 2016-08-01 | 2016-08-01 10:10:10 | {1,2}
 2  | str 2  | 2016-08-02 | 2016-08-02 10:10:10 | {1,2,3}
 3  | str 3  | 2016-08-03 | 2016-08-03 10:10:10 | {1,2,3,4}
(3 rows)
```

### Large csv files

The above function imports data two times (to temporary and target tables).
For large files this may be a serious loss of time and unnecessary load on the server.
A solution would be splitting a csv file into two files, one with header and one with data.
Then the function should look like this:

```
create or replace function import_csv(header_file text, data_file text, table_name text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
begin
    create temp table import (line text) on commit drop;
    execute format('copy import from %L', header_file);

    execute format('create table %I (%s);', 
        table_name, concat(replace(line, ',', ' text, '), ' text'))
    from import;

    execute format('copy %I from %L (format csv)', table_name, data_file);
end $$;
```

### Altering column types

You can try to automatically change the column types based on their content.
You can succeed if you are dealing with simple types and data in the file consistently retains a specific format. However, in general it is a complex task and functions listed below should be considered only as an example.

Determine a column type based on its content (edit the function to add desired conversions):

```
create or replace function column_type(val text)
returns text language sql as $$
    select 
        case 
            when val ~ '^[\+-]{0,1}\d+$' then 'integer'
            when val ~ '^[\+-]{0,1}\d*\.\d+$' then 'numeric'
            when val ~ '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d$' then 'date'
            when val ~ '^\d\d\d\d-\d\d-\d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$' then 'timestamp'
        end
$$;
```

Alter column types using the above function:

```
create or replace function alter_column_types(table_name text)
returns void language plpgsql as $$
declare
    rec record;
    qry text;
begin
    for rec in
        execute format(
            'select key, column_type(value) ctype
            from (
                select row_to_json(t) a_row 
                from %I t 
                limit 1
            ) s, json_each_text (a_row)',
            table_name)
    loop
        if rec.ctype is not null then
            qry:= format(
                '%salter table %I alter %I type %s using %s::%s;', 
                qry, table_name, rec.key, rec.ctype, rec.key, rec.ctype);
        end if;
    end loop;
    execute(qry);
end $$;
```

Use:

```
select alter_column_types('new_table');

\d new_table

               Table "public.new_table"
   Column    |            Type             | Modifiers 
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id          | integer                     | 
 a_text      | text                        | 
 a_date      | date                        | 
 a_timestamp | timestamp without time zone | 
 an_array    | text                        |
```

(well, proper recognition of array types is quite complicated)